# Reset Callbacks so they fire each time a user scrolls to a section in fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I commented a fadeOut for some of the sections but cannot get them to reappear after scrolling a second time and I don't know javascript well enough to find the right solution. How would I do that?

```
  $(document.body).fadeIn(1000);
  $(document).ready(function() {

      'use strict';

      // variables
      var $isH1First   = $('.first .is-animated h1'),
          $ispFirst    = $('.first .is-animated p'),
          $isH1Second  = $('.second .is-animated h1'),
          $ispSecond   = $('.second .is-animated p'),
          $isH1Third   = $('.third .is-animated h1'),
          $ispThird    = $('.third .is-animated p');

      // initialize fullPage
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({

     //   navigation: true,
          scrollingSpeed: 1400,
          resetSliders:true,
          fitToSectionDelay: 1000,

        afterLoad: function(index, nextIndex) {
         if( nextIndex === 1 ) { 
              $isH1First.addClass('animated fadeInLeft').css('animation-delay', '.05s'); 
              $ispFirst.addClass('animated fadeInLeft').css('animation-delay', '.45s'); 
            }
         },
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex) {
          // first animation
          if( nextIndex === 2) { 
      //      $isH1First.addClass('animated fadeOutUp'); 
      //      $ispFirst.addClass('animated fadeOutUp');
            $isH1Second.addClass('animated fadeInDown').css('animation-delay', '.45s'); 
            $ispSecond.addClass('animated fadeInDown').css('animation-delay', '.85s'); 
          }
          // second animation
          else if( nextIndex === 3 ) {
      //      $isH1Second.addClass('animated fadeOutUp'); 
      //      $ispSecond.addClass('animated fadeOutUp');
            $isH1Third.addClass('animated bounceInDown').css('animation-delay', '.45s'); 
            $ispThird.addClass('animated flipInX').css('animation-delay', '.85s'); 
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather late ,I use velocity.js to get nice animations and I wanted to only show the animations once and not every time the section loads.

If I understand you correctly then you are trying to achieve the opposite which was the default behavior for me.

A small example of my code :

```
if (index === 1) {
        //slide 1 animation
        if (!$jq(".refine").is(":visible")
        {
            $jq(".refine").velocity("fadeIn", {duration: 2000});
        }
    }
```